# Spring boot disable test in CI

Tags: spring-boot, github-actions

I have spring boot application that I test on github CI. There is one test that I want to disable if its CI. There is environment variable in CI : `CI` that is set to `true`.

I am fighting with `@DisabledIf` annotation and cannot get it to work, I tried things like:

```
@DisabledIf(expression = "#{systemProperties['CI'] == true}")
@DisabledIf(expression = "#{systemProperties['CI']")
@DisabledIf(expression = "#{systemProperties['CI'] == 'true'")
@DisabledIf(expression = "#{systemProperties['CI'] == 'true'")
@DisabledIf(expression = "#{systemProperties['CI'].equals("true")")
```

but non of these work.

Comment: Why not use `DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable`?

Comment: in any of the test which fails, try printing the value of `systemProperties['CI']` expression

Comment: `#{systemProperties['CI'].equals('true')}` might work, the expression. None of your attempts are closing out the SPeL expression properly `}` is missing in all of them

Comment: thanks for your answers. DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable works